# How to use custom App type in place of IO?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, io-monad

I'd like to use a custom application type in place of `IO` in my program and use it with functions like [`race_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.2.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:race_) from the `async` library.

Specifically, I'm keen on passing two computations of type `App` to `race_`. Since `race_` only accepts values of type `IO`, I wrapped those computations with `return`.

While this type-checks, I can see that neither of the computations is actually executed.

Here's a minimal example¹ illustrating the issue:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables        #-}

module RaceTest where

import           Control.Monad.Reader           ( MonadReader
                                                , ReaderT(..)
                                                , runReaderT
                                                )
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class         ( MonadIO
                                                , liftIO
                                                )
import           Control.Concurrent.Async       ( race_ )

data Env = Env { val :: !Int }

newtype App a = App
    { unApp :: ReaderT Env IO a
    } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadReader Env)

runApp :: Env -> App a -> IO a
runApp env app = runReaderT (unApp app) env

main = runApp (Env 24) simpleApp
 where
   simpleApp :: App () = do
     liftIO $ putStrLn "About to spawn threads"
     liftIO $ race_ (return firstAsync) (return secondAsync)
   firstAsync  :: App () = liftIO $ putStrLn "First async"
   secondAsync :: App () = liftIO $ putStrLn "Second async"
```

How can I run these computations of type `App` using `race_`?

---

¹ <sub>While it would be simple in this example to just get rid of the `App` type, in the application I'm building, I have `App` and `Env` types that allow logging using `co-log` similar to this [setup](https://github.com/kowainik/co-log/blob/master/co-log/tutorials/2-custom/Custom.md). That's something I don't want to lose.</sub>

Comment: You might consider using the "unliftio" package http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio that provides functions like `race_` http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-0.2.12/docs/UnliftIO-Async.html#v:race_ that work over any monad with a `MonadUnliftIO` instance (basically, they handle all the newtype wrapping and unwrapping for you). `ReaderT` over `IO`  already has such instance, and you could derive one for your newtype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your computations are not getting executed, because you're not actually passing them to `race_`. Instead, you're passing two `IO` computations, which return your `App` computations as a result. But not executing them.

In order to get them executed inside `IO`, use your function `runApp` that you already have. Since you'll need to pass an environment to it, and I'm assuming you'll want to use the same environment as `simpleApp` itself has, you can use `ask` to obtain it out of the `MonadReader` context:

```
simpleApp :: App () = do
     liftIO $ putStrLn "About to spawn threads"
     env <- ask
     liftIO $ race_ (runApp env firstAsync) (runApp env secondAsync)
```